# AngularJS, Primefaces, XHTML, navbar issue?

Tags: html, angularjs, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Im doing a web-app where i want a navigation bar on top of every xhtml page. Im using AngularJS for this, but it doesnt work and i cant find out why. Im suspecting that i have to work differently with Angular when im in xhtml but maybe someone can provide answers/fix the code!

***index.xhtml***

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      ng-app="directivemodule"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-fancy-modal.css"/>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css"/>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/build.css"/>

        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-fancy-modal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        
        
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="ng-app" value="directivemodule">
                <div id="navbar" ng-include="navbar.xhtml">
            
                </div>
            </f:passThroughAttribute>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

***app.js***

```js
(function(){
 'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('directivemodule', []);
    
    app.directive("navbar", function()
    {
        return{
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: "navbar.xhtml"
        };
    });
    
});
```

Comment: When asking questions about problems with a client side framework, it's for experts of the particular client side framework easier to answer if you leave out all the server side code responsible for producing the HTML output from the question. You should do as if you're basically having a plain vanilla HTML page. Open JSF page in browser, rightclick and do *View Source*. Copypaste that to a `test.html` file and breakdown it to a fullworthy MCVE snippet by removing lines which do not contribute to the actual problem (e.g. all that CSS is very unlikely to cause any problems).

Comment: Namely, in the context of this question, JSF is merely a HTML code generator. If you however discover during creating the AngularJS-targeted MCVE that the JSF-generated HTML output is in first place wrong, which caused that AngluarJS can't do its job, then you should take a step back and leave out the client side framework from the question. You should instead ask how to write JSF code in such way that it produces exactly the expected HTML output so that you can ultimately just advance with your AngularJS thing.

Comment: Note that saving a page as **test.xhtml** will cause it to behave differently than saving as **test.html**.